# Python Key Error=0 raise KeyError(key) from err

Tags: python, pandas, axis, keyerror, kaggle

First, thank you for taking the time to view this question.

I'm a newbie to kaggle.
[spaceship titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/code/samuelcortinhas/spaceship-titanic-a-complete-guide#Feature-engineering)
I'm currently studying the guide in the link above.

Fixed Eli5 import issues for newer Pythons.(No longer compatible).

```
# Joint distribution of Group and HomePlanet
GHP_gb=data.groupby(['Group','HomePlanet'])['HomePlanet'].size().unstack().fillna(0)
GHP_gb.head()

# Countplot of unique values
sns.countplot((GHP_gb>0).sum(axis=1))
plt.title('Number of unique home planets per group')
```

I have made good progress up to this point, but the code in In[24] throws an error that I can't figure out, as shown below.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

8 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 0
```

Change the axis value to 0 or

```
sns.countplot(GHP_gb>0).sum(axis=1)
```

If you make changes like the ones above, you'll see some errors, but you'll still be able to see the data.

It doesn't look like there's an error in the code, so how do I know what's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the kaggle notebook, but I cannot reproduce the error.
If the local environment has been used, it may relate to the version of python dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I am using google colab.